# vbscript, excel 8.0 password on worksheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have Googled without much luck. Basically each creation of a excel spreadsheet (based on a template), needs to be password protected. Can this be done?

```
'______________________CreateExcel()____________________________________

    Function CreateExcel()    
        SELECT DATA FROM SQL TABLE

If objStructure.BOF = False And objStructure.EOF = False Then
Do While objStructure.EOF = False
                    Call CreateActualExcel()      
objRsExcel.Fields("Field") = objStructure.Fields("Field")


objStructure.MoveNext
            Loop      
     End If
    End Function
'......................End CreateExcel()..................................

'______________________CreateActualExcel()________________________________

Sub CreateActualExcel()

    Dim objSFSO
    Dim strCon, strSQL

        strFile = " Staffing_List_" & Clng(Timer()) & ".xls"
    Set objSFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    objSFSO.CopyFile conFolder & conTemplate, conFolder & strFile
    Set objSFSO = Nothing
    Set objRsExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

    strCon = _
              "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
              conFolder & strFile & ";" & _
              "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;maxscanrows=1;"";"

    strSQL = "Select * From [Sheet1$]"

    objRsExcel.Open strSql, strCon, 3, 2

End Sub

'......................End CreateActualExcel()............................
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can pass the password as an additional parameter when you save the file.

excelObj.SaveAs "C:\Example.xls",,"your-password"

I haven't tested this but I found this blog post about it:

http://qtp.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/vbscript-excel-password-protect.html